# Azure pipeline to post PR in Microsoft Teams

Tags: azure, azure-devops, microsoft-teams, pull-request

Whenever someone raised a pull request in Azure DevOps, I want to an automatic post to be trigged in one of the teams in Microsoft teams.

Many repositories provides this alert to stack. But, I want this on Teams. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/teams/#integrating-microsoft-teams-with-azure-devops-services

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things

- integrate [Azure Repos with Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/integrations/repos-teams?view=azure-devops) and the you will be able to listen for some activities like PR

[image]

- integrate via Service Hooks:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't have permission to configure service hooks :) Have to connect with the admin.